# How can I use PowerShell or a cmd "dir" to get the contents of multiple, but similar paths?

Tags: powershell, cmd

For example, I want the contents of the "Last" folder in the structure below.  The various path structures are identical except for the first two levels.

- C:\zyx-wvu\abc\Level3\Last
- C:\tsr-qpo\def\Level3\Last
- C:\nml-kji\ghi\Level3\Last

In PowerShell I get close with:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\*-*\*
```

...but it doesn't return any results (as in it never finishes) when I try:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\*-*\*\Level3
```

Comment: The wildcard character does not count the path-separator character (``\``).  You would need to catch both levels: `Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Folder?\*\Level3\Last`

Comment: When I try this, the cursor returns to the next line and acts as if it is waiting on results, but nothing is displayed.

Comment: Your example doesn't match what you're actually doing then.

Comment: I updated my question to more accurately reflect the structure I am working with.  I can't get to "level3" or "last".

Comment: Works just fine for me with the sample paths you provided. Please double-check your actual paths.

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\*-*\*
```

will only show you what's in the second layer behind anything with a hyphen in c:\

aka it will show

```
c:\1-2\alpha
c:\1-5\beta
```

etc...

What you want is

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\*-*\*\*
```

or more likely you want

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\*-*\* -recurse
```

if you want to find paths with the SAME name... you could group them together, and pull out anything with more than one finding... you didn't ask very specifically what you wanted, but here's some ideas.

```
get-childitem -Path c:\*-*\*\* | group-object -property basename | where count -gt 1 | select -expand group
```